# Javascript - filtering a list: how can I find an intersection between an array with objects including array and an array?

Tags: javascript, filter

How can I filter a list (array with objects) with a filter list (array) and find intersections? I add to the filter array every time a user checks the checkbox clicking on particular filter. When user unchecks the checkbox I remove from filter array. Somehow whateever i try doing, i always return the entire reviews array including ALL not filtered items. Why? Thanks!!

```
const reviews = [
{
  title: "item 1",
  filter_results: {
    features: ["message", "call"],
    pricing: ["Business", "Free", "Whatever"],
    rating: [1]
  }
},
  {
  title: "item 2",
  filter_results: {
    features: ["call", "copy", "paste"],
    pricing: ["Business"],
    rating: [1]
  }
},
  {
  title: "item 3",
  filter_results: {
    features: ["copy", "connect", "wifi"],
    pricing: ["Free",
    rating: [2]
  }
 }
]

const filteredReviews = {
 pricing_options: ["Business"],
 popular_features: ["copy, call"],
 rating: [1, 2]
}

const update = (reviews, categoryName) => {
  if (categoryName) {
    return reviews.filter(review => {
      return review.filter_results[categoryName].filter(value => {
        if (filteredReviews[categoryName].includes(value)) {
          return review
        } 
      })
    })
  } else {
    return reviews
  }
}
  update(reviews, "pricing")
```

Comment: why is `popular_features` an array with combined items? what result do you expect?

Comment: is this `.includes` some sort of custom function that checks the existence of the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return a boolean on `filter` callback, and do a better filtering mechanism:

```js
const update = (reviews, filters) => {
  if (filters) {
    return reviews.filter(review => 
        Object.entries(filters)
          // Change to `some` if the filters are OR'ed instead of AND'ed
          .every(
            ([filter_key, filter_values]) =>
              // Change `some` to `every` if all elements in the
              // userFilter[*] array MUST be matched instead of some of them
              filter_values.some( (filter_value) =>
                review.filter_results[filter_key]
                  .includes(filter_value)
              )
          )
    )
  } else {
    return reviews
  }
}

// Fix variables names:
// - `userFilters` contains the filters selected by the user
// - `filteredReviews` contains the array of reviews, resulting from
//   filtering the reviews using the `userFilters`

// Fix key names: Use same keys than in reviews, instead of:
// - `pricing_options` => `pricing`
// - `popular_features` => `features`
const userFilters = {
  pricing: ["Business"],
  // Transformed/fixed to 2 values. Was it a typo?
  features: ["copy", "call"],
};

const filteredReviews = update(reviews, userFilters);
```

Comment: actually that answer does not work. first, it must be not     Object.entries(filters) but   Object.entries(filteredReviews) and also then it always returns false because filter_value is not a string but an array of strings (for example:  features: ["call", "copy", "paste"])

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand what is `filteredReviews` used for. Can you explain that, please?

Comment: yes. so i have reviews.  a user has a number of filters (categories such as features, pricing etc). within each filter category there is a checkbox with the filter (    pricing: ["Business", "Free", "Whatever"]). when user checks a checkbox im adding to filteredReviews, whenever user uncheck a checkbox, i remove from filteredReviews. in update function then i use filteredReviews to filter reviews and render that. let me know if i should explain something else

Comment: Added `userFilters` handling. Add comments about variables and keys naming.

Comment: sorry, one more question. how could change the function to return not exclusivly - what I mean: for the property "rating" (see in code), I want to return all reviews that have the choose rating --> if I choose 1 AND 2, I want to show reviews with 1 AND 2. Now I would show none because the review with 1 doesnt have 2 and so on.

Comment: Do you mean like changing `filter_values.some` to `filter_values.every` ?

Answer (score 0):

Filter callback function should return a "boolean", you are returning arrays which evaluate always to "true".